# Html rendering elements out of order

Tags: html, css, out

I'm having trouble with page layout. I'm having to use a mix of tables and divs. The problem occurs with the footer and the div containing the table. The footer is being displayed above that div but in the html it is my last element inside  the "main_container".

```
<style>
 #sidebar {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
          }
 #TblContain {
               position: relative;
               display: block;
               float: right;
               width: 70%;
             }

 #footer {
           position: relative;
           width: 100%;
           display: block;
         }
</style>
<div id="main_container">
<div id="head">
</div>

<div id="nav_bar">
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<div id="TblContain">
 <table></table>
</div><!--endTblContain-->
</div><!--endContent-->

<div id="footer">
</div><!--endFooter-->
</div><!--endMainContain-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if clear:left; doesn't work, try adding clear:both; to the footer in the css.

Comment: since its working and you used someone's advice,
you should select he's answer as the right one, for two reasons:
1. reward the helper with points.
2. future visitors will find the solution a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier, than trying to float the divs.  In addition it will allow your page to be re-sizable and your individual content area scrollable.

```
<html>
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
     <div id="header" style="overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:50px;right:0px;background-color:#FF0000;"></div>
     <div id="leftNav" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px; right:200px; bottom:50px;background-color:#00FF00;"></div>
     <div id="mainContent" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:50px; left: 200px; right:0px; bottom:50px;background-color:#0000FF;"></div>
     <div id="footer" style="overflow:hidden; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; height:50px;right:0px;background-color:#FFFF00;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/ugoli3/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
clear: left;
```

to the footer.